# Collections.nCopies not creating copies of list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created a `List` of Lists with a default size set.  Therefore, I am adding the data to the lists using the `set` method.

**My Code:**

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test2 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<List<String>> keys = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(3, new ArrayList<>()));
    List<String> values = keys.get(2);
    values.add("Hello");
    values.add("One Two");
    keys.set(2, values);
    List<String> tempList = keys.get(1);
    tempList.add("Now adding at 1");
    keys.set(1, tempList);
    System.out.println("Position 1 " + keys.get(1).toString());
    System.out.println("Position 2 " + keys.get(2).toString());
}
}
```

**My Output:**

```
Position 1 [Hello, One Two, Now adding at 1]
Position 2 [Hello, One Two, Now adding at 1]
```

Why is it doing this? The first data get's appended onto the second as well? What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
List<List<String>> keys = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(3, new ArrayList<>()))
```

In this statement it's not creating three new instances of `ArrayList<>`. It creates *one* instance of it and creates a list with three references to the *same* instance. Hence each location in the list of lists is a reference to the same `ArrayList` instance.

The simplest thing you can do to get around this is to use a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numCopies; i++) {
    keys.add(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

An equivalent solution using Java 8's streaming API:

```
IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<String>()).forEach(keys::add);
```

Or you can create `keys` in one go like so:

```
List<List<String>> keys = IntStream.range(0, numCopies)
                                   .mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<String>())
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

We use `i -> new ArrayList<String>()` instead of `ArrayList<String>::new` because there is an `ArrayList<T>` constructor that takes in a single integer argument for the initial capacity, which means that it ends up actually being `new ArrayList<String>(0)`, `new ArrayList<String>(1)`, and so on, which is not what we want.

A more elegant option is to use `Stream.generate`:

```
Stream.generate(ArrayList<String>::new).limit(n);
```

Comment: You probably want to use something else besides `ncopies`

Comment: `.mapToObj(ArrayList<String>::new)` isn't doing what you think. Since mapToObj() takes an `IntFunction<? extends U>` you're actually getting `new ArrayList<String>(0)`, `new ArrayList<String>(1)`, etc. You probably want something like `.mapToObj(x -> new ArrayList<String>())` or `.mapToObj(x -> new ArrayList<String>(INITIAL_CAPACITY))` instead.

Comment: @Draemon that's a very important subtlety. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I would personally use `Stream.generate(() -> new ArrayList<>()).limit(n)` instead of an `IntStream`.

Comment: @MCEmperor That is much better. I will add it to the answer.